Cosmos Db and EF Core: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to track an entity of type 'Order' because its primary key property 'Id' is null
so I'd been using CosmosClient to develop my app, but I wanted to implement Domain Events which are not supported with CosmosClient, so I had to switch to EF Core. When using EF Core I can't get my entities from the db, because of the Id being saved as "id" in cosmos.
I tried to use JsonProperty("id"), Column("id") and also AsNoTracking, but all give the same results. What should I do?
My BaseEntity class:
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [JsonProperty("id")] 
    [Column("id")]
    public virtual string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public DateTime? ModifiedAt { get; set; }
}

My ComosDb document:
{
    "OrderNumber": "1000000000",
    "PatientData": {
        ...
    },
    "Results": {
        ...
    },
    "Status": 2,
    "id": "1000000000",
    "CreatedAt": "2024-03-21T17:58:50.432892+01:00",
    "ModifiedAt": "2024-03-24T01:24:17.52464Z",
    "_rid": "7NA1AKlBYQ8MAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/7NA1AA==/colls/7NA1AKlBYQ8=/docs/7NA1AKlBYQ8MAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"0000a702-0000-5600-0000-65ff80c10000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1711243457
}


Verify that EF Core has properly mapped the id attribute of your CosmosDB document to the Order entity's Id property.

@Balaji how do i do that?


Cosmos Db and EF Core: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to track an entity of type 'Order' because its primary key property 'Id' is null

The above error mostly occurs when Entity Framework Core tries to track an entity with a null primary key or EF Core is not correctly mapping the id property from your Cosmos DB document to the Id property of your Order entity. The below code which doesn't have null for primary key and it maps the id attribute of Cosmos DB document to the Order entity's Id property.
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseCosmos(
            "AccountEndpoint=https://<acc_name>.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=<primary_key>", "firstDb");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .ToContainer("secondCont")
            .HasPartitionKey(o => o.Id); 

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .Property(o => o.Id)
            .ToJsonProperty("id");
    }

    public async Task InsertOrderAsync(Order order)
    {
        await Orders.AddAsync(order);
        await SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

public class Order : BaseEntity
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public virtual string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public DateTime? ModifiedAt { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new YourDbContext())
        {
            var newOrder = new Order
            {
                OrderNumber = "10000001",
            };

            await context.InsertOrderAsync(newOrder);
            Console.WriteLine("New order inserted successfully.");
        }
    }
}

In the above code Order entity to be mapped to the Cosmos DB container named "secondCont" and map the Id property of the Order entity to the JSON property named "id" in the Cosmos DB document.
Output:
New order inserted successfully.

Saved item in Cosmos DB:
{
    "id": "c7613229-6d72-4b6b-b29c-9673be54cdde",
    "CreatedAt": "2024-04-27T12:24:55.3344193Z",
    "Discriminator": "Order",
    "ModifiedAt": null,
    "OrderNumber": "10000001"
}

